# Auto-vectorization with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, auto-vectorization

I would like to vectorize matrix-vector products in my code. I try to use auto-vectorization in GCC, and it just doesn't work at all and I have no clue how to make it work out. Right now I try a very simple example code:

```
#define N 200000
double a[N] __attribute__(( aligned(16) ));
double b[N] __attribute__(( aligned(16) )) ;
double c[N] __attribute__(( aligned(16) )) ;

void f()
{ 
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
    }
}

int main( int argc,char** argv )
{
    f();

    return( 0 );
}
```

I use gcc version 4.9.2 and compile with flags (for completeness)

```
-Wall -O3 -ftree-vectorize -march=native -msse2 -fopt-info-vec-missed -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1 -std=c++11 -fdiagnostics-color=auto
```

I get the following output (I really do not understand what the stuff means, but the bottom line clearly is that vectorization doesn't work out):

```
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref b[i_11]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref c[i_11]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref a[i_11]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: virtual phi. skip.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: not ssa-name.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: use not simple.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: not ssa-name.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: use not simple.
optimization2.cpp:6:6: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:12:13: note: not vectorized: no vectype for stmt: vect__4.6_1 = MEM[(int *)vectp_b.4_9];
 scalar_type: vector(4) int
optimization2.cpp:12:13: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:6:6: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:14:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref b[i_12]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref c[i_12]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref a[i_12]
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: virtual phi. skip.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: not ssa-name.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: use not simple.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: not ssa-name.
optimization2.cpp:10:2: note: use not simple.
optimization2.cpp:16:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:12:13: note: not vectorized: no vectype for stmt: vect__4.28_2 = MEM[(int *)vectp_b.26_9];
 scalar_type: vector(4) int
optimization2.cpp:12:13: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:16:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
optimization2.cpp:16:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
```

I have tried many many other things and other codes but never could get anything vectorized. What is the trick?

Comment: When I compile that (also with gcc 4.9.2 and the same command line, although `-march=native` may mean something different), adding `-save-temps`, I get the same output from the optimizer and assembly that contains `vmodapd` and `vaddpd` (i.e., is vectorized). I think the optimizer notes are about other parts of the code that can't be vectorized. Are you certain the addition in your generated asm isn't vectorized?

Comment: @Wintermute: From other examples I was under the impression that GCC explicitly states if a loop has been vectorized (verbosity level doesn't change that). The code consists of what I have posted, there are no other loops for which vectorization could fail. I haven't looked at assembly code. But there does not seem to be a speed gain with or without vectorization activated (assuming -O2).

Comment: That there's no/little performance gain is because gcc 4.9.2 generates SSE instructions (albeit not SSE2) even with `-O0`. SSE2 instructions are only generated with `-O3`, but their advantage over SSE1 in this scenario is limited. Why the optimizer output does not mention any of this is anyone's guess, but I'm looking at the generated asm, where it is plainly visible.